# CONSOLIDACIÓN DE INFORMACIÓN

Tags: wordpress

Estoy trabajando en wordpress, tengo un cliente del cual mediante woocommerce se va a gestionar el inventario de una farmacia, por tanto se crean los productos junto con sus metadatos, como se ve en la siguiente imagen, hay campos adicionales tales como el lote, el registro invima, etc.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito crear una tabla que me vaya mostrando el consolidado de la información tal como se evidencia en el siguiente pantallazo de excel.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He visto que la información se está almacenando en dos tablas, wp_postmeta y wp_post, en la tabla wp_postmeta al hacer la consulta desde la DB puedo encontrar que bajo el post_id me trae los datos del comprador, nombres, etc.
por ejemplo post_id=833 puedo encontrar varios datos que me son de utilidad para construir la tabla, mirar la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema radica es que cuando voy a consultar los otros datos del pedido, es decir, el invima, el código cum, etc.estan con otro código post_id, por ejemplo en este caso 722 y 723, sé que esos son los datos del mismo pedido 823 pero no se porque está cambiando dicho consecutivo, sé que puedo relacionar ese post_id y amarrarlos a los datos del pedido para consolidar la información en una sola vista, pero no entiendo la relación del 722 con el 823 (como ejemplo) no se cómo está relacionados entre si y como hacer para que al hacer la consulta puede sacar toda la información.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Busca info de como consultar los datos serializados de wordpress

Answer (score 0):

'wp_posts' debería almacenar tanto el producto como las ordenes, ya que esta tabla corresponde a entradas de wordpress y 'wp_postmeta' almacena únicamente metadatos relacionados con la entradas en 'wp_posts' así que cada entrada de 'wp_posts', si tiene metadatos, tendrá un registro con su id en 'wp_postmeta'.

Para que quede más claro el id 833 es tu post y el id 723 son los metadatos de ese post.

La forma correcta de traer todo sería con get_post_meta( $post_id ), esto te va a regresar un array en este caso `get_post_meta( 833 )`, debería recuperar todos los metadatos que tienes con el id 723

Comment: Buenas Tardes.
Gracias por tu respuesta, estoy emepzando con el desarrollo, es posible que me indiques la manera correcta de la hacer la consulta?

Answer (score 0):

Aclarame una cosa, no termino de entender si lo que quieres es hacer una consulta del producto o del pedido.

Si es del producto sería así:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         =>  'product',
);

$posts = get_posts( $args );

foreach($posts as $post ) {

    the_title();

    $post_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID);

     print_r($post_meta);

}
```